# How can I install Kubernetes operator and executer on docker based airflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I'm using Puckels docker file to build and run dags. I'm trying to create new dags that I can execute on a Kubernetes pod but I'm not sure how to get it working on the docker's airflow container.
I tried adding to the docker file

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[kubernetes]'
```

then I tried adding the following line into my dag:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators import KubernetesOperator
```

This is the error message I get:

```
cannot import name 'KubernetesOperator' from 'airflow.contrib.operators' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KubernetesPodOperator` is defined under the `kubernetes_pod_operator`. You should be using:

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
```

Please also check out [this Airflow documentation page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/kubernetes.html).